# referencing appSettings from usercontrols

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, web-config, appsettings

In my .ascx usercontrol i'm trying to dynamically generate links using a value i've stored in  web.config.

```
<a href="<%$appSettings.MYPATH%>/file.aspx">link</a>
```

and when i try running, i get a parser error

```
Literal expressions like '<%$appSettings.MYPATH %>' are not allowed. Use <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$appSettings.MYPATH%>" /> instead.
```

I know i'm probably missing something relatively minor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <a href="<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.appSettings("MYPATH") %>">link</a>
```

should work (it at least does on the IIS server I use). (Unfortunately it's more verbose)

Answer (score 4):

```
<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"] %>
```

EDIT:Don't forget the ***=***

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

.ascx

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

in code behind

```
Literal1.Text = "<a href='" + appSettings.MYPATH + "'/file.aspx">link</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

More accurate answer will be next:

```
<a href="<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["param_name"] %>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a colon instead of a dot and add `runat="server"`:

```html
<a href="<%$ AppSettings: MYPATH %>/file.aspx">link</a>
```

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad%28VS.100%29.aspx#sectionToggle3) isn't very clear on this point, but ASP.Net Expressions are for use within server tags.  Thus, if you want to use one in a plain html tag, you must add `runat="server"` so that the tag is processed on the server where the expression will be evaluated.